# Image menu on responsive WordPress

Tags: menus, navigation, responsive

1) Why WordPress only use based on "text" menus (navigation) only?
Maybe the answer is "it is for SEO and mobile responsive WordPress".
Am I correct? any other opinions?

2) What if I create "image navigation menu" for only PC version and create "mobile navigation and responsive" maybe select box.
Is it possible?

I have found `is_mobil()` and I think it can be done.

Please see this link `http:www.tourtips.com/` and see the beautiful image navigation menu. I really want to use it but I worry about mobile version.
Is there any way to keep this image menu for PC version and create another mobile or small size menu for smaller devices? if it's possible, what codes I should use?

I think some of codes should be loaded depends on devices such as:
`if...is_mobile()...` and CSS parts... and loading scripts...

Any more things I should worry? any tips? any tutorial links?

Comment: You are asking _what_ to do, while this site is more about _how_ to do it. Please try to formulate your requirements first and focus question on what you need help with to achieve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking for, but I think you need some general suggestions. So:

1) **Websites are made by [three layers](http://www.slideshare.net/ReverendJuice/3-layers-of-the-web-part-1)**. Wordpress (like others good CMS) creates "only" TEXT menu because this is the (fundamental) semantic layer.

1-b) Then, you can always add a presentation layer (css) or a behaviour layer (javascript) in order to create an Image menu, also if Wordpress gives you just the semantic layer. You can reach this with some techniques, one of these is the **[image replacement technique](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/)**.

2) If you have understood the two points above, you can also understand that **is not so useful to generate on the server side two different html**. All that you need is to create a good semantic HTML (Wordpress does it!) and after, via css and javascript, you can add all your images and behaviours.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I read it breifly and will try to understand soon.  if...is_mobile() function show_mobile_header() else function show_pc_header()... like this I want to do. and on pc_header it shows image header, and on mobile_header shows text menu (header) like normal wordpress. is it possible? then I might be 1 html for header.

anyway thanks for your great answer and I will study more.

Comment: Yes, of course is possible, you can reach this using the [wp_is_mobile()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) function. You can use this function to generenate two html inside the file header.php

Comment: Good to era Pulla ;)